# DRF Authentication is not working in frontend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, I created registration app. I added `registration API`, `Login API` and `User profile API`. I tested three API's in `Postman` it is giving results. In my project I used `djangorestframework-simplejwt` authentication. When I test with browser it is not working what I have to do please anyone can help me out to achieve this.

In `settings.py`

```
from datetime import timedelta

# JWT Configuration
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}



# JWT Settings
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=20),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .........
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    .........

]
```

In `Views.py`

```
class UserLoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        q = QueryDict(request.body)
        query_dict = q.dict()
        json_object = json.dumps(query_dict, indent=4)
        reqBody = json.loads(json_object)
        email = reqBody['email']
        password = reqBody['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        print('user')
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            token = get_tokens_for_user(user)
            Account = customer.objects.get(email=email)
            request.session['email'] = Account.email
            request.session['id'] = Account.id
            request.session['name'] = Account.firstname
            request.session['cust_status'] = Account.cust_status
            request.session['os_name'] = Account.os_name
            request.session['user_type'] = Account.flag
            request.session['username'] = str(Account.firstname) + str(Account.lastname)

            return Response({'token': token, 'msg': 'Login Success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'errors': {'non_field_errors': ['Email or Password is not Valid']}},
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

After login testing `API` with authentication

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def test_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Allowed")
```

Error I am getting is

```
Test View
GET /example_view
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Token

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Comment: hi, firstly, it would help to get an answer if you provide complete code, e.g. there aren't any import statements in your views snippet, neither in settings.py. Also I think your settings is incomplete, e.g. since you are using Django REST framework I'd expect to see  `rest_framework` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Giving complete code helps someone to copy it, try to run it, and help you; if code is incomplete, people will just give up (as I will do now, sorry for that!) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `authentication_classes` decorator because you are using JWT authentication.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def test_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Allowed")
```